Print List of Generic Interface in Java 11
I have this property in a class:
private final List<KafkaInterface<EventWhateverDTO>> producers;

Code of interface:
public interface KafkaInterface<T> {
  void produceEvent(Map<String, String> headers, T event);
  void produceEvent(String topic, Map<String, String> headers, T event);
  default List<String> getActions() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
  default Class<T> getEvetTypeClass() {
    return null;
  }
}

and the class
import org.apache.avro.message.SchemaStore;
import org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBuilderBase;

@AvroGenerated
public class EventWhateverDTO extends SpecificRecordBase implements SpecificRecord {

...

}

I'm using:
    log.info(String.format("producers: %s.", producers));

What would be the suitable way to print the list?

What information do you seek as an output? Is it the topic name, headers, etc? What is not working currently or is there any error of sort?

Why do you think that what you’re already using is not suitable?
